# Copy files between folders on linux

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have to copy many files from different folders.

1. Dont know how many are in the source folder
2. Knows that the folder has the same name of the contained file
3. Only folders tha contains some file extensions needs to be copied

**Example of the source Folder structure**

Source folder has the following structure

```
root
 - folder1
    - folder1.txt
 - folder2
    - folder2.csv
 - folder3
    - folder3.txt
```

**Example of the destination Folder structure**

Destination folder should be like this following structure

```
root
 - folder1
    - folder1.txt
 - folder3
    - folder3.txt
```

To accomplish the generic copy and recreating the folder structure I have used the following script:

```
cp src/**/*.txt dest/
for file in $(ls *.txt); 
   do mkdir -p source/${file%.*}/ && mv $file dest/${file%.*}/; 
done
```

First of all I copy all the file in the destination folder. Based on the assumption that every file is inside a folder which has the same name then I am moving the files recreating the original structure. This script effectively works very well.

Now the requirement has changed to support multiple level folder structure. E.g.

```
root
 - folder1
    - folder11
       - folder11.txt
 - folder2
    - folder2.csv
 - folder3
    - folder3.txt
```

How can I adapt the script to remain generic?

Comment: You may encapsulate your source folders into an array and adjust your script in the loop over this array.

Comment: Any reason not to use `rsync`?    This seems to work for me (mimicking your structure, not copying empty ones).  `rsync -av --include='*.*' --prune-empty-dirs  lorenzo/src/ lorenzo/dst`

Comment: BTW, mickp's answer does a very good job of following relevant best-practices here -- consider patterning off it, especially the use of shell globbing instead of [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and the care to quote all expansions. (If you run your original code through http://shellcheck.net/, consider reading the wiki pages linked from the warnings it throws, particularly [SC2045](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2045) and [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar

src=some/src/path
dest=some/dest/path

for f in "$src"/**/*.txt; do
    d=${f#"$src"} d=$dest/${d%/*}
    mkdir -p -- "$d" || continue
    cp -- "$f" "$d"
done
```

Comment: you dont need shopt for coping files I believe.

Comment: @Gox You need it for the recursive globbing `**`.